# Go back to home(activity_main) from navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have been struggling with this since yesterday morning. I am familiar with C++(just stating I do have programming experience). I am learning android programming. When my app starts it brings up an activity. I suspect it is

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

In my navigation drawer, I have 3 items. One is called "Piggy Bank" which is suppose to be the navigation home. "Graph" and "Settings" are the other 2. I want it so when someone clicks on "Piggy Bank" in the navigation drawer it goes back to the original screen that loads when the program starts. This needs to be done without creating a new activity, the data in the home screen is important and should not be cleared when going back to it. It should contain the data that was left there.

Here is what I tried

```
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        if (id == R.id.nav_PiggyBank) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            // getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
            // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
            // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
            client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_Graph) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new Graph())
                    .commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_Settings) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame
                            , new UserSettings())
                    .commit();
        }


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

here is my activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: whats in your activity_main ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place everything that's inside your if (id == R.id.nav_PiggyBank) { ... } case in your onCreateMethod of the activity. Inside the if-case you should tell the FragmentManager to replace the current fragment container (R.id.content_frame) with your PiggyBankFragment...like you've done in the both other if-else cases ;-)

**Update:**

If you want to use the NavigationDrawer I recommend to use multiple fragments with content and just one activity, that holds the fragment container and your navigation drawer. So the structure of your app looks like this:
1. You create your PiggyBankActivity which contains the fragment_container and the navigation drawer. Nothing else - no piggy bank content
2. You create a PiggyBankFragment which contains all of the content you want to display on this "home" page
3. You use FragmentManager and FragmentTransactions in onNavigationItemSelected to replace the fragments and show the desired content.

You can refer to this documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html 
or this example
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/
;-)

Comment: I tried that and I get this error(red line under the second argument). Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.example.crims.piggybank.MainActivity', required: 'android.app.Fragment' less... 

replace (int, android.app.Fragment)
in FragmentTransaction cannot be applied
to (int, com.example.crims.piggybank.MainActivity)

Comment: Thank you, as stated I am new to android.I do not know what "Fragment_container" are... I am assuming a fragment?  Much less the manager and transactions. But... I do have a general idea of what you're saying and that is what I am trying to do. I will try again you did clear up some things.

Comment: (y) ...you could also try to use this link: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/ It provides a detailed example of what you want to achieve ;-)

Comment: Glad to help you.